# IPtables GeoIP libxtables

Tags: linux, iptables, geoip

I was about to install geoip module for iptables. Installation goes fine until I checked the module.

It says:

```
iptables: match "geoip" has version "libxtables.so.10", but "libxtables.so.11" is required.
```

I haven't found anything about this. What's the problem and solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your geoip module is compiled with `libxtables.so.11`, but you have `libxtables.so.10` in your system.

You can either update the package that provides `libxtables.so.10` to new version, or install an old version of geoip module that uses old version of the library.

Comment: And what package provide libxtables, please? :)

Comment: You have not provide any distribution in your question. Ubuntu has `libxtables10` and `libxtables11` packages as seen [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxtables) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxtables). You can find necessary packages for other distributions similarly.

Comment: UPDATE, now it is

    `iptables: match "geoip" has version "libxtables.so.11", but "libxtables.so.10" is required.`